# Botões não animam corretamente e página fica pequena em dispositivos móveis

Tags: html, css, html5, css3

Nessa página possuo dois problemas:

1. Os botões de dentro da **body** não esmaecem como os que estão dentro do **footer**.
2. A página não se adapta ao dispositivo que está sendo exibida.

Mas o principal problema mesmo é o 1º.

Não entendo praticamente nada de **html** e criei essa página do zero. Quem puder me ajudar ficarei imensamente grato! :)

```css
html {
    font-family: 'Exo 2', sans-serif;
    text-align: center;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    list-style-type: none;
    background: #DAE1E9;
}

body, header {
    margin: 50px;
}

footer {
    margin: 25px;
}

h3 {
    color: #D76018;
    transition: 0.5s;
}

p {
    color: #D76018;
    font-size: 11px;
    transition: 0.5s;
}

.botoes-principais {
    font-size: 18px;
    padding: 18px;
    color: #DAE1E9;
    text-decoration: none;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 256px;
    display: list-item;
    margin: 10px;
    position: relative;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    transition: 0.5s;
}

.botoes-secundarios {
    font-size: 16px;
    padding: 5px 2.5%;
    color: #DAE1E9;
    text-decoration: none;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 256px;
    display: list-item;
    margin: 10px;
    position: relative;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    transition: 0.5s;
}

.botao-wpp {
    background: linear-gradient(75deg, rgba(0, 154, 68) 0%, rgba(0, 132, 61) 100%);
}

.botao-wpp:hover {
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0) 0%;
    color: rgba(0,154,68,1);
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 2px rgba(0,154,68,1);
}

.botao-ig {
    background: linear-gradient(75deg, rgba(255,208,64,1) 0%, rgba(215,96,24,1) 100%);
}

.botao-ig:hover {
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0) 0%;
    color: rgba(215,96,24,1);
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 2px rgba(215,96,24,1);
}

.botao-fb {
    background: linear-gradient(75deg, rgba(14,155,216,1) 0%, rgba(3,88,124,1) 100%);
}

.botao-fb:hover {
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0) 0%;
    color: rgba(3,88,124,1);
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 2px rgba(3,88,124,1);
}

.avaliacao {
    background: rgba(215,96,24,1);
}

.avaliacao:hover {
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0) 0%;
    color: rgba(215,96,24,1);
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 2px rgba(215,96,24,1);
}

.botao-email {
    font-size: 16px;
    padding: 10px;
    text-decoration: none;
    border-radius: 256px;
    display: list-item;
    margin: 10px;
    position: relative;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0) 0%;
    color: rgba(3,88,124,1);
    width: 312px;
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 2px rgba(3,88,124,1);
    transition: 0.5s;
}

.botao-email:hover {
    background: rgba(3,88,124,1) 100%;
    color: #DAE1E9;
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 0px rgba(3,88,124,1);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.1.1/css/all.css'>
    <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Exo%202'>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" name="viewport>
</head>
<header>
    <a <img src="logo-cabecalho.png" width="330" height="49" /></a>
</header>
<body>
    <h3>Redes sociais</h3>
    <a href="https://www.whatsapp.com" class="botoes-principais botao-wpp"><i class="fab fa-whatsapp"></i>&nbsp;whatsapp</a>
    <a href="https://www.instagram.com" class="botoes-principais botao-ig"><i class="fab fa-instagram"></i>&nbsp;instagram</a>
    <a href="https://www.facebook.com" class="botoes-principais botao-fb"><i class="fab fa-facebook"></i>&nbsp;facebook</a>
</body>
<footer>
    <a href="https://www.facebook.com" class="botoes-secundarios avaliacao" target="_blank">avalie a gente no <i class="fab fa-facebook"></i></a>
    <a href="https://www.maps.google.com" class="botoes-secundarios avaliacao" target="_blank">avalie a gente no <i class="fab fa-google"></i></a>

    <a href="mailto:email@gmail.com" class="botao-email"><i class="fa fa-mail-bulk"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;email@gmail.com</a>
</footer>
</html>
```

Comment: Por favor, esclareça seu problema ou forneça detalhes adicionais a fim de destacar exatamente o que você precisa. Da forma como está escrito atualmente é difícil dizer com exatidão o que você está perguntando.

Answer (score -2):

A tag `header` está antes da tag `body` e o `footer` depois, o que não pode acontecer, pois a tag body é o corpo do documento, e só será mostrado o que tiver dentro dessa tag.

Dentro de `head` temos a

```html
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

que define o nível de zoom inicial quando o usuário visita a página e o viewport com a largura do dispositivo.

Estrutura correta:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>
<body>
    <header>
    </header>
    <footer>
    </footer>
</body>
</html>
```

No CSS, os botões do `footer` são diferentes na transição, pois, as suas cores são fixas, não tendo degrades entre 2 cores como os botões de WhatsApp, Facebook e Instagram.

Comment: Muito obrigado mesmo!!! :D